# jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException after quarkus update

Tags: quarkus

Currently I'm updating my application from 2.16.1.Final version quarkus to 3.6.3. It also has quarkus-kafka-streams in dependencies. After update I tried to execute quarkusDev but it failed with jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology and qualifiers [@default] even if I only add quarkus-kafka-streams in dependencies without implementing anything. Has anybody come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed Kafka streams extension needs a Topology to work. You can provide a CDI bean using `@Produces` annotation.

You can have more information in https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams